# bash: /usr/bin/top: Input/output error

Tags: ssd, crash, read-only

After pushing the laptop through Android Studios and browsers and ... the laptop crashed

RAM 6 and Core i5 processor

ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64-bit

gnome 3.28.2

I was waiting to get out of the regiment but unfortunately it didn't happen and I turned off the laptop after 15 minutes and after landing without any reason and pressure the laptop regrows and most programs just stop browsing and no longer open and For example, the top command does not work and gives the following error

bash: / usr / bin / top: Input / output error

And after restarting it also gives an error and the restart cannot be resembled in the picture below
[image]
A few months ago I had a problem with my hdd hard drive. After many years of high pressure with Android studio, the same problem occurred and then I used the SSD hard drive but it happened again after four months.
And now I don't know what the problem is. Is there hardware?
Does this increase with the increase in RAM?

Comment: IO error should make it clear.  A read-only file system means (a) you mounted it RO and not RW which I suspect unlikely, or (b) a logical error was detected on device & it automatically flipped from RW to RO to protect data. You need to `fsck` (file system check) your drive ASAP, fix errors and it can then be re-mounted as RW. I'd also check the health of your device (using SMART, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools), and it's easiest to do from a 'live' environment as it cannot be used/mounted for `fsck` to operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: You may have a defective HDD/SSD

**Let's first check/repair your filesystem...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Then let's check the Disk SMART Data...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start the `Disks` application
- select your HDD/SSD
- view the `SMART Data` window
- take screenshot(s) and upload them to your question

Comment: Thanks
I used the repair option and the problem is now resolved.
I will send the requested information if this happens again.

Thankful

Comment: @navidjahan Good news! Just to make sure that you don't still have other unsolved problems, please go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.