# Disk starts failing with Input/Output error shortly after boot

Tags: boot, mount, hardware, disk

My laptop is about 4 years old, running Ubuntu 16.04. This morning, after using it normally for about 30 minutes, I noticed the CPU spiking and the laptop hanging. Within a minute it was completely locked up. I did a hardware restart, and it started working again, but a few minutes later, the same thing happened. After a few more tries and doing more on the command line when things went haywire, I'm pretty sure it's some kind of disk failure.

For example, I've been getting errors [like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/input-output-error-when-accessing-a-directory), however `dmesg` isn't reporting any issues - at least initially. However, after some time, even normal command line commands like `ls` and `cat` start failing with either "Input/Output error" or "command not found" (though after reboot they work fine again). By the time the machine is in this state `dmesg` is also failing with that error.

I then ran a storage test from the BIOS and it is failing.

I also tried booting from a Live CD and mounting the drive in readonly mode so that I could do some backups (similar to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216954/bash-usr-bin-top-input-output-error)), but the drive does not show up properly and I have not successfully been able to mount it despite trying a number of things. `fdisk -l` is not identifying any of the volumes as "linux filesystems" but instead reports "unknown".

However, I can login normally on the laptop, and if I'm fast enough, navigate to a directory and back up some files to a remote server (via SCP), until things start going haywire. It boots fine, applications run, and then after a minute or two things start to fail.

So my question is basically: any idea what's going on here? Or how I can further troubleshoot the situation? One thought I had was to open it up and check my hard drive cables. I can (and probably will) also replace the drive, but it'd be nice to be able to back things up in bulk before doing that. I'm also a bit wary of the "login and scp" approach because I worry about some underlying corruption that may be happening.

Comment: Backups is something to have *before* the drive fails. When I/O errors are shown it's almost always too late.

Comment: 16.04 is due to be EOL in April (so very soon) so at the same time as replacing the HD consider the advice in [this resource](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-16-04-end-of-life)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Thankfully, I do have backups of everything important on there, and yes I will definitely be upgrading to 20.04 asap

Comment: I would shutdown, remove hard drive, put the disk in a plastic bag, and put in your fridge for about 30mins. Blow out any air ducts in the laptop. It look like a heat issue & a failing component on the drive, I seen this before. This may give you enough time to recover/backup some files. I have actually done this & it worked for a longer time.

Comment: After login startup gparted (if necessary install it from the repository).  In the menu of gparted you will find some things that may help (repair - information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop on this, it appears to have been some kind of hard drive failure, though a mysterious one. I was able to purchase a new drive and the laptop is up and running with no issues.

I was also able to purchase an adapter to convert my old hard drive into a USB drive and then used this [data recovery guide from ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) and `ddrescue` to image and mount the drive onto an external drive. So far as best I can tell, the drive is fully in tact with zero data loss (which confuses me a bit as to what was happening, but oh well).

I will likely not use the drive anymore either way, since I don't trust it and have the image now.

Hope this helps someone else in a similar situation.